# Spring and Spring Boot Compatibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to check the compatibility of Spring framework and Springboot versions?

I recently switched from Spring v4.3.20.RELEASE to Spring v5.2.20.RELEASE
and Springboot v1.5.17 to v2.1.10.RELEASE
And now, I am facing many compatibility issues.
I am having a hard time figuring out the compatible versions.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use at least Spring Boot 2.3.12 with Spring Framework 5.2.20.

Note that Spring Boot 2.3.x and 2.4.x are no longer supported, and 2.5.x support ends soon. Refer to release notes on the Spring Boot wiki at GitHub, and the support matrix at spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Spring Boot normally manages your dependencies, so once you are on the current version you would not want to specify the Spring Framework version yourself.

Comment: How did you determine that at the very least Springboot v2.3.12 must be used with Spring v5.2.20?

Comment: It should be Spring Framework 5.2.15 for Spring Boot 2.3.12. [official link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-system-requirements)

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach for find compatibility.
Go on [spring-boot maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot)

[image: maven repository]

In this case spring-core and context (in compile dependencies) is 5.3.27..
spring-boot 2.7.12 is compatible with Spring 5.3.27

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to refer to the official documentation for the latest version, you may refer to [System Requirements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements) section. For older versions, you may google with ["spring boot" "system requirements"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spring%20boot%22%20%22system%20requirements%22) and look for your version.